Triggering an EventBridge when video streams stops
I would like to trigger a lambda when stream ends, for debugging purposes I have configured a log so it would output it to cloudwatch.
I was able to trigger the eventbridge and get the log message, with python code:
eventbridge.put_events(
    Entries=[
        {
            "Source": "kinesisvideo.my-stream",
            "DetailType": "Kinesis Video Stream Segment End",
            "Detail": json.dumps({
                "streamName": "my-stream",
                "eventType": "END"
            })
        }
    ]
)

but for actual scenario of stopping a video stream for the channel my-stream it fails,
I see the video in the Media playback so I'm sure it is streamed well.
I made use of KVS WebRTC Test Page for streaming
Can somebody give me some tips? how to configure the rule correctly or suggest more approaches how to debug this issue,
apparently it doesn't getting triggered in the event of ending the stream.
Thank you all!
